# Once add wemosdk.jar in Android App, how to find none WeMo devices?

Tags: android, upnp

I have an Android app which included “wemosdk.jar" as a lib to find WeMo devices.
Now to search none WeMo Devices, I want to use cyberlink lib (cyberlink-core-2.1.0.jar). From the ControlPoint, it only contains “WeMo” devices and I can not find other none WeMO devices.
If I removed the wemosdk.jar from the app, the cyberlink-core-2.1.0.jar works

Answer (score 0):

Both WeMosdk.jar and cyberlink-core-2.1.0.jar included org.cybergarage, 
should have UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.DexException in compile